# Strips at top and side for conditioned RasterStack plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, raster, lattice

For the following `RasterStack`, the individual layers are grouped according to two factors (upper case letters, and lower case letters).

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(replicate(6, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))
names(s) <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(LETTERS[1:2], letters[1:3]), sep='_'))
spplot(s)
```

[image]

I'd like to avoid repeating the levels' labels, ideally by having a single strip at the top with the labels `A` and `B`, and a single strip down the left or right side with labels `a`, `b` and `c`. Something like the following, but for a `RasterStack`.

```
library(latticeExtra)
useOuterStrips(
    xyplot(y~x|grp1+grp2, 
           data.frame(x=runif(600), y=runif(600), 
                      grp1=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=100), 
                      grp2=rep(letters[1:3], 200)),
           strip=strip.custom(style=1), as.table=TRUE))
```

[image]

I'd like a `lattice`-based solution (including `rasterVis::levelplot`), since that way the plot I'm attempting to create will fit in nicely alongside other work. That said, I'm open to a `ggplot2` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I was overthinking this...

```
library(tidyr)
cbind(as.data.frame(s), coordinates(s)) %>%
  gather(group, val, -x, -y) %>%
  separate(group, c('grp1', 'grp2'), '_') %>%
  levelplot(x=val~x+y|grp1+grp2, aspect='iso', 
            scales=list(alternating=FALSE, tck=1:0)) %>%
  useOuterStrips
```

[image]